# android billing

Tags: android, android-billing

Народ помогите разобраться! Продаю контент в приложении и получаю от гугла разные odrer_id 12607194618218675, GPA.1300-58-0922-48113, 9328385919432941.31364878274217. Этот GPA.1300-5**8-0922-48113 все ок могу отследить и т.д. остальные вообще темный лес. Кто в курсе помогите пожалуйста.